# installing http://fullcalendar.io/

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4, asp.net-ajax

I have this:

Index.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="calendar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: false,
            events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"
        });
    });

    //Set up the date picker and wire it's onSelect function
    //to the FullCalendar plugin.
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    });

    //Set some defaults for the fullCalendar, including the URL to
    //get the data from...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            theme: true,
            defaultView: "basicWeek",
            firstDay: 1,
            events: "/Schedule/GetCalendar/"
        });
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

AgendaController:

```
public class AgendaController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private long ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
    {
        TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

        return (long)Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds);
    }   
}
```

I am trying to install the free FullCalender Ajax plugin: http://fullcalendar.io/
But if I run the application and go to:`http://localhost:41787/Agenda` nothing is displayed. I put the `<div id="calendar"></div>` in the Index view file. But nothing happens. I don't see the Calendar.

And I put the scripts in the BundleConfig:

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
             "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
             "~/Content/fullcalendar.print.css"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
             "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js" ));
```

but I dont understand why I get the 404 not found error

ok, the scripts are running now correctly, but still dont see anything if I go to:

```
http://localhost:41787/Calendar


Request URL:http://localhost:41787/Scripts/fullcalendar.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,nb;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
```

oke, I have it now like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("hallo");
    });



    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month'
        },
        defaultDate: 'new Date()',
        editable: true,
        events:
            [
            {
                title: 'Bi-weekly Meeting',
                start: '2014-07-09',
                color: 'red'
            },
            {
                title: 'Tournament',
                start: '2014-07-07',
                end: '2014-07-10',
                color: 'darkorange'
            },
            {
                title: 'Test Event',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2014-07-28'
            }
            ]
    });
```

So I see the Hallo message if I load the page, but by this line: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({`

it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Index:141
(anonymous function)
```

oh, oke, I triied like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month'
                },
                defaultDate: 'new Date()',
                editable: true,
                events:
                    [
                    {
                        title: 'Bi-weekly Meeting',
                        start: '2014-07-09',
                        color: 'red'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Tournament',
                        start: '2014-07-07',
                        end: '2014-07-10',
                        color: 'darkorange'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Test Event',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2014-07-28'
                    }
                    ]
            });

and now it works :)

        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a javascript debug tool to see if your events are firing? Check the browser to ensure it's loading all the javascript files

Comment: yes, you are right, but I look in the Script map and the content map, and all the files are there, I also put them in the BundleConfil.cs

Comment: oke, problem solved, thank you anyway for the tips :) –

Comment: Why not add an answer to help anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: ? I did that.  see my solution. I put everything in $(document).ready(function () {} and it works now :)